# How to get all elements except the n'th element in a List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a list of 10 items.

```
List<char> chars = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];
```

I need a new List containing all the elements in the List except n'th (say, 3rd item `'C'`). I don't want the original list to be altered since I need it later.

Another option is, I can clone the list and remove the item, but then all the items after the n'th has to be shifted up.

Is there a way to get the list using Linq?

**Edit:**

A character can occur multiple times in the List. I want only the occurance at 'n' to be removed.

Comment: I believe you could use `chars.Take(2).Concat(chars.Skip(3))` but I really don't know for sure...

Comment: It returns the correct result but it will iterate through the list twice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure, using the [overload of `Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) that takes an index parameter:

```
var allBut3 = chars.Where((c, i) => i != 2);  // use 2 since Where() uses 0-based indexing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) method.

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

```
List<char> chars = new List<char>(){'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};
var newlist = chars.Where(n => n != chars.ElementAtOrDefault(2));
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/qy2lYK).